# Tkinter: Getting information from mainwindow to a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with Tkinter where I would get data from the user and display them in a new window. But I'm struggling with displaying the information in the new window. I have tried using the .get() and just printing but the new window opens with no data on it.

I have tried using messageBox but it also doesn't seem to be what I'm looking to happen either.

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *


class peronalInfo_GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        #create window and set title
        self.mainWindow = Tk()
        self.mainWindow.title("Property Taxes)")
        window_width = 330
        window_height = 150
        
        # get the screen dimension
        screen_width = self.mainWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.mainWindow.winfo_screenheight()
        # find the center point
        center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)
        # set the position of the window to the center of the screen
        self.mainWindow.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        #self.mainWindow.geometry("250x160")
        
        #Label 1 --> User Input name
        self.nameLabel = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "Enter your name: ")
        self.nameTextBox = Entry(self.mainWindow, width = 25)
        self.nameLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.nameTextBox.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        
        #Label 2 --> User Input address
        self.addressLabel = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "Enter address: ")
        self.addressTextBox = Entry(self.mainWindow, width = 25)
        self.addressLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.addressTextBox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        #Label 3 --> User Input phone number
        self.phoneNumberLabel = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "Enter phone number: ")
        self.phoneNumberTextBox = Entry(self.mainWindow, width = 25)
        self.phoneNumberLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.phoneNumberTextBox.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        
        #Label 4 --> User input college major
        self.collegeMajorLabel = Label(self.mainWindow, text = "Enter your college major: ")
        self.collegeMajorTextBox = Entry(self.mainWindow, width = 25)
        self.collegeMajorLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.collegeMajorTextBox.grid(row = 3, column=1)
        
        #Create Buttons for event handling
        self.displayInfo = Button(self.mainWindow, text = "Display Information", bg = "#BB8FCE", command = self.openNewWindow)
        self.exitButton = Button(self.mainWindow, text = "Exit", bg = "#F1948A", command = self.mainWindow.destroy)
        self.displayInfo.grid( row = 5, column = 0, padx = 15, pady = 15)
        self.exitButton.grid ( row = 5, column=  1)
        #Loop
        self.mainWindow.mainloop()
        
    def openNewWindow(self):
        newWindow = Toplevel(self.mainWindow)
        newWindow.title("Display Info")
        newWindow.geometry("350x150")

        #Display User Info
        self.displayName = Label(text = self.nameTextBox.get(), row = 1)
        self.displayAddress = Label(text = self.addressTextBox.get(), row = 2)
        self.displayNumber = Label(text = self.phoneNumberTextBox.get(), row = 3)
        self.displayMajor = Label(text = self.collegeMajorTextBox.get(), row = 4)
            
            
def main():
    callGUI = peronalInfo_GUI()

main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a second instance of `Tk`. If you need a second window, use `Toplevel`. That may not be the only problem, but it's definitely one of the problems.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have two problems: First: you create `Labels` but you  forgot `.grid()` or `.pack()` to show them. Second: every widget should have `parent` as first value - you create `Labels` without `newWindow` as `parent` so it will automatically show widgets in `mainWindow`

Comment: did you run your code in console? It shows error `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-row"` because you put `row=...` inside `Label` but you have to use `.grid(row=...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't run code in console because you would see error

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-row"
```

and this could partially resolve problem

---

I see two problems:

**First:**

You use

```
var = Label(..., row=1)
```

but it has to be

```
var = Label(...)
var.grid(row=1)
```

And this generates error.

**Second:**

You create `Label` without `parent` as first value - so it will use `mainWindow` as `parent` and it will display `Label` in first window instead of new window.

You need:

```
Label(newWindow, ...)
```

---

```
    def openNewWindow(self):
        newWindow = Toplevel(self.mainWindow)
        newWindow.title("Display Info")
        newWindow.geometry("350x150")

        #Display User Info
        self.displayName = Label(newWindow, text=self.nameTextBox.get())
        self.displayName.grid(row=1)
        
        self.displayAddress = Label(newWindow, text=self.addressTextBox.get())
        self.displayAddress.grid(row=2)
        
        self.displayNumber = Label(newWindow, text=self.phoneNumberTextBox.get())
        self.displayNumber.grid(row=3)
        
        self.displayMajor = Label(newWindow, text=self.collegeMajorTextBox.get())
        self.displayMajor.grid(row=4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did run the program in VS Code but it only displayed the new window completely blank without showing me any error. I didn't realize that I put the rows and columns without using the .grid. I don't understand why the newWindow doesn't need the self. with it. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: you can use `self.newWindow` if you need it. Without `self.` you have local variable - so you can't access it in other functions. If you will have to access `newWindow` in other function then you will need `self.newWindow` in all places.

Comment: I was thinking about implementing another function later to get the information and save it on a text file. I might have to use `self.` then! Thank you for your help.